# Showing that a divisor of zero in a commutative ring with unity can have no multiplicative inverse"

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> A divisor of zero in a commutative ring with unity can have no multiplicative inverse.

I don't understand why this statement is true.

So for $a,b$ in the ring, $ab=0$ by zero divisor.

How can we guarantee that there does not exist $c$ such that $ac=1$?

Comment: Dear @nancy : I spotted the duplicate question in the related questions, indicating that it probably appeared in the list that appeared as you typed your question. Please try to do a search before you post a new question.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** Suppose $a$ has a multiplicative inverse, and multiply both sides of $ab = 0$ by $a^{-1}$.

Comment: is that a contradiction? Assuming ab=0 for a,b not 0, then if there is inverse of a then cab=b=0 then ab is not zero divisor?

Comment: Yes, by hypothesis $b \neq 0$ but the assumption that $a$ has a multiplicative inverse lead to the conclusion that $b = 0$, which is indeed a contradiction.

Comment: Appreciate your concise and exact example

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it helpful. I wouldn't call it an "example", however: the argument is totally general, in that it applies to every zero divisor in every ring.

Comment: @Nancy: If you find Travis' answer useful, you can upvote it (click the up arrow on the left of the answer). Furthermore, if you feel that it has completely answered your question, you can accept it by clicking the tick to the left of the answer.